# Form validation with Yup: Error appears without touching field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

In my project (next.js) I'm using MUI, formik and yup.

There's one problem: As soon as I enter something in the first input field, the error appears in all the other input fields. There is something wrong with the "error" property in the code above, but I couldn't figure out what and how to change it. Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  surname: yup.string().required("Surname is missing"),
  name: yup.string().required("Name is missing"),
});

    export default form() {
      const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
          surname: "",
          name: "",
        },
        validationSchema: formSchema,
        onSubmit: () => {
          //logic
        },
      });
    
    return (
       <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
       <TextField
             focused
             color="secondary"
             sx={{
                 m: 0.5,
                 marginBottom: 3,
              }}
              id="surname"
              name="surname"
              label="Vollständiger Vorname"
              value={formik.values.surname}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={!!formik.errors.surname}
                  />
       <TextField
             focused
             color="secondary"
             sx={{
                 m: 0.5,
                 marginBottom: 3,
              }}
              id="name"
              name="name"
              label="Name"
              value={formik.values.name}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={!!formik.errors.name}
                  />
       <ButtonDefault text="Analyse starten" type="submit" />
       </form>
    ) 
    }
```

Comment: Before posting here it could be a good idea to go look at the documentation for the library you're using. Checking for `touched` as described by the answer below is clearly shown in all of the validation examples.

Comment: I agree. You need to read and understand how we should use some library.

Comment: Hey guys, to be honest, it wasn't easy to find the solution (see below - there was something else missing). I've tried to check for `touched`, but since `helperText` was missing, it didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for touched value as well

```
error={formik.touched.surname && formik.errors.surname}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me. Additionally, I had to add the following line of code for each input field: helperText={formik.errors.surname ?? " "}, helperText={formik.errors.name ?? " "} etc.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you've referenced `errors.surname` in both fields

```
           <TextField
             focused
             color="secondary"
             sx={{
                 m: 0.5,
                 marginBottom: 3,
              }}
              id="name"
              name="name"
              label="Name"
              value={formik.values.name}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={!!formik.errors.surname}   <----
            />
```

The property for this error should be `!!formik.errors.name`.

Hope this was helpful

Comment: Sorry, this was just a copy&paste error. In my code I've referenced  !!formik.errors.surname and !!formik.errors.name...I've edited the code in my question.